# Galois Biography References

Tags: reference-request, math-history, mathematicians

I'm currently starting work on a project about Evariste Galois, and while I'm familiar with the basic details of his life (French, revolutionary, genius, headstrong, dead), and those details paint an amazing picture of him, I have not been able to find a comprehensive biography of him in English. My command of French is unfortunately poor and so reading any French biographies would be out of the question at this time. I was hoping you could point me to an authoritative English biography (if such a thing exists), and if not, to compilations of his personal correspondence or the like.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are a lot of references in English, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Évariste_Galois).

Comment: This question would fit better on http://hsm.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: The kid died before he was $\;21\;$ : what correspondence and stuff? Anyway, read here: http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Galois.html  That is likely the most, or close to, you're going to obtain in english.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I am aware of his early death. However, he seems to have written enough for Camille Jordan to base his work on it. I'm also aware of letters he wrote to his brother, his lover(s), and his friends, though I don't know if these have been translated.

Comment: For a full book, see : Laura Toti Rigatelli, [Evariste Galois 1811–1832](https://books.google.it/books?id=zCjyBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1996).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look up the following links,

[Galois quote about his refused work](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2562/galois-quote-about-his-refused-work)

[Did Evariste Galois create the entire group structure concept?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2883/did-evariste-galois-create-the-entire-group-structure-concept/2885#2885)

[Why was Évariste Galois killed?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/9/why-was-%C3%89variste-galois-killed/2434#2434)

As already pointed out in comments, this question is better suited 
[here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

**Edits**

[Galois's 
last 
mathematical 
testament 
in 
the 
form 
of a 
letter 
to 
his 
friend 
Auguste 
Chevallier 
is 
reproduced 
here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

[Galois last letter](http://people.math.umass.edu/~tevelev/391A_2015/galois_lc.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. Would I have to re-ask the question over at hsm?

Comment: @JorgeMedina http://uberty.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Peter_M._Neumann_The_Mathematical_Writings.pdf